# MTM/VSTS "insert shared steps" query has different default per user

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, microsoft-test-manager

These users never had MTM installed locally but seems to have different default for test case shared steps query.

[image: one of the tfs user has the query below set as default]

I'm not sure where to find these queries saved. or how to clear if it's cache related.

I know if there is MTM installation on user local machine, it will save user config settings `mtm.AddSharedStepsGrid` somewhere in `systemDrive:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TeamTest\v*"` but this is also occurring on user machines without MTM installation.

Comment: What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

It has different default per user, cause the user have used/changed the query before.

TFS web portal will **auto cached the last query option which user have selected**.

You could test this in your side, just change some options, close the “insert shared steps” query, then open it again, it will changed.

Since there is not any button to save the "insert shared steps" query, you could only Run it. I think this is by designed as a temporary storage per user instead of the "save" option.

Answer (score 0):

We now only have the first row i.e. Work Item Type in group Shared Steps. That wouldn't be different per user.

Comment: We have some of our users with a different default somehow. I've personally tested this on different user's machine to confirm. you're right most users have the WIT clause only as a default but there are some users that had it different